# SSRS - Fixed column scrolling not working when viewed in Browser

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have created a report which has too many columns to display on the screen.

As such I have set the leftmost column as `Fixed Data` to make the report readable.

When previewing the report through either Visual Studio or Report Builder the freezing of the columns works without problems but when running the same report through Report Manager (no matter which browser I use) the columns do not freeze.

I have tested and get the same issue when freezing header rows and have tested with several new and previously existing reports.

The strange thing is I could swear this has worked correctly in the past.

Comment: When you say "Fixed Data" and "freezing" are you talking about the "Keep header visible when scrolling" setting?

Comment: Hi Steven, no the 'keep header visible when scrolling' setting doesn't seem to work so instead I go to the Column Groups properties and changed the 'Fixed Data' setting to True. As I say this works when previewing the report but doesn't work when the report is deployed and I view it through Report Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue while working with SSRS 2008 and trying to display the report with Internet Explorer 11. I solved the problem on Internet Explorer 11 by going to the Tools option menu (gear icon on the right upper corner of the screen). Click on Compatibility View Settings. On "Add this website" textbox, you should be able to see the domain of your organization, something like "organization.com". Click on Add. Leave "Display intranet sites Compatibility View" and "Use Microsoft compatibility lists" checked as it comes by default. Click on Close. You should see IE changing its appearance now a little bit. Test the report again. Next time you open the web browser, it will have this configuration already set.

Answer (score 0):

It only works if you collapse the show/hide report parameters bar.

[image]

Once you have hidden that the fixed rows and columns will work just fine in the browser.